# Calling functions in postgres like the package in Oracle {call schema_name.package_name.function(?,?,?,?,?,?) with placeholders

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql

Converting a package from oracle to POSTGRES But POSTGRES does not support the package so firstly convert the packages to function through Ora2pg tool.

Situation is That the package is being called from the java code as

```
{call schema_name.package_name.functionName(?,?,?,?,?,?)} in ORACLE

COULD I ABLE TO CALL THE sAME FROM THE JAVA CODE AS WITH  placeholder


{call schema_name.functionName(?,?,?,?,?,?)} in postgres
```

When i am running it in java then the placeholder for string type is being converted into unknown type in postgres.

```
setString(2,"action");
```

of CallableStatement not able to convert it into varchar type but to unknown type

Problem is that setString in postgres is converting to unknown type

Comment: What is your problem? Do you want to remove the `package_name` package?

Comment: @zaratustra I am not able to run this statement through Prepared statement It is giving exception in java program .

Comment: It is giving exception when i run it in java . I will edit my question to give you a better explanation

Comment: There are too few lines of java code to be able to find out your problem